# Run a Qt app in a different language?

Tags: linux, qt, localization, internationalization

I'm working on a Qt application that used to be a KDE application.  In the old days, I just had to use some syntax like:

```
KDELANG=de ./my_app
```

That ran my_app in German, and only my_app.  It might not have been KDELANG, but it was some environment variable like that.

I've spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to coax this answer out of Google, and I give up.  There must be some way to run a Qt (4.5 if that matters) application in some other language without switching over my entire locale to get there.

Comment: how do you know it's not working?  Does your app definitely work in German already?  Setting the environment KDELANG=de only works if:
1. the app has German content, and
2. the app uses the KDELANG envvar to set the locale

Answer (score 6):

I tried it with the KDE game Kolf and

```
(export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8; kolf)
(export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; kolf)
```

did the trick for me to switch it into German or English.

I verified it with the QT application qtparted

```
(export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8; qtparted)
```

also comes up in German on my English desktop. Obviously I had to install the German language files to get the translated app working.

Comment: You can just do: LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 qtparted

That will limit the effects to a single application.

Comment: @Matthew The () which create a subshell have the same effect, as the export will only be visible inside the subshell.

Answer (score 2):

Just like any other Linux application, Qt applications follow a rather convoluted way how the application message locale is selected: environment variable `LANGUAGE` is given preference over `LC_ALL`, `LC_ALL` over `LC_MESSAGES`, `LC_MESSAGES` over `LANG` ([details](https://superuser.com/q/392439)).

So any one of the following commands works to change the application's locale for messages, as returned by `QLocale::system().name()`:

```
LANGUAGE=de ./my_app
LANGUAGE=   LC_ALL=de ./my_app
LANGUAGE=   LC_ALL=   LC_MESSAGES=de ./my_app
LANGUAGE=   LC_ALL=   LC_MESSAGES=   LANG=de   ./my_app
```

**Notes:**

- I tested this with Qt 5.12 under Lubuntu 19.10 (means, using the LXQt desktop).
- It is entirely up to the Qt application how to adapt to the application locale as returned by `QLocale::system()`. It may not evaluate `QLocale::system()` at all, or fail to find its translation files etc..
- You can also give the above commands in the form `env LANGUAGE=de ./application`. The `env` command has some more options to control which environment its child process will see.
- The locale values specified in the environment variables (here `de`) do *not* have to correspond to any locale that is installed system-wide and listed in `locale -a`.
- When specifying only a language (like `de`), Qt will automatically expand it with a default country and return that in `QLocale::system().name()`, for example `de_DE`.
- When specifying a wrong value (such as `xy`), Qt will return the default `C` locale from `QLocale::system().name()`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's a long story, but it turns out the translations are, in fact, busted, and that's the whole underlying problem here.  The obvious thing I tried first works fine.  Since this isn't KDE, I just used plain:

```
LANG=de ./my_app
```

Now that I've fixed the bug in the debugging code (oh, the irony) I can plainly see that the translation files (which do exist) aren't getting loaded.  Ah.  Alrighty then.  Carry on.  Nothing to see here.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using plasma desktop, install language package from under System Setting -> locale
and run app as follow : `KDE_LANG=fr ./appName` 
fr represents french, you can choose language of your interest.