# How to force QLocale::system to change

Tags: c++, qt, localization, qt4

I need to test my application translation to non-English language very often, and this is very uncomfortable to change the whole operating system language just to do this simple check.
How can i change Qt-detected system language using environment variables for example?
or with command-line parameter.

I try to change `LANG`, `LANGUAGE` environment variables, but it has no effect.
However, under GNOME it has!

UPD: code i'm using such code to determine the system locale and load appropriate translation:

```
QTranslator app_translator;
if (!app_translator.load ("app_" + QLocale::system ().name (), app_tr_dir))
    qWarning ("Can't load app translator file for locale %s from %s", qPrintable (QLocale::system ().name ()), app_tr_dir.toLocal8Bit().data());
else
    app.installTranslator (&app_translator);
```

P.S. My OS is Kubuntu 13.10, Qt version is 4.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing you can use something like that (just correct main function):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QLocale localeUsedToDeterminateTranslators = QLocale::system();
    Q_FOREACH(QString a, app.arguments()) {
        const static localeParam = "-locale:";
        if (a.startsWith(localeParam)) {
           localeUsedToDeterminateTranslators = QLocale(a.mid(sizeof(localeParam)-1));
           break;
        }
    }
    ... // your normal code
```

Then when you run you app you can just run it with extra parameter: `./yourAppName -locale:nl`. See [documentation of QLocale](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qlocale.html#QLocale-2) for possible values.

---

Edit: I've found even better approach, there is a [method `QLocale::setDefault`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocale.html#setDefault), so this should work even better:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Q_FOREACH(QString a, app.arguments()) {
        const static localeParam = "-locale:";
        if (a.startsWith(localeParam)) {
           QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(a.mid(sizeof(localeParam)-1)));
           break;
        }
    }
    ...
    QTranslator app_translator;
    if (!app_translator.load ("app_" + QLocale().name (), app_tr_dir))
         qWarning ("Can't load app translator file for locale %s from %s", qPrintable (QLocale().name()), app_tr_dir.toLocal8Bit().data());
    else
         app.installTranslator (&app_translator);
```

Comment: So, your advice is just use custom command line parameter? Ok, that can helps.
But i'm just curious - how do the `QLocale::system` determine the currenly selected locale. It's better to understood this than create appropriate `QLocale` object by brute force :)

Comment: somewhere in your code you should use locale to determinate which translations to load. In your code you have `QLocale::system ().name ()` so you just replace that with `localeUsedToDeterminateTranslators.name()`.

Comment: Under Gnome `QLocale::system` understood `LANG` env variable changing, so looks like it is KDE bug/feature. Thanks, i'll mark your answer as a solution of my problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can always change the locale by QLocale::setDefault() method. here's an example from one project:

```
void Language::setCurrentLanguage(Language::Languages language)
{
    if (language == Language::Arabic) {
        QLocale l(QLocale::Arabic, QLocale::SaudiArabia);
        QLocale::setDefault(l);
        dynamic_cast<MangoApp*>(qApp)->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
        dynamic_cast<MangoApp*>(qApp)->removeAllTranslator();
        dynamic_cast<MangoApp*>(qApp)->loadQtTranslator();
        dynamic_cast<MangoApp*>(qApp)->loadMangoTranslator();

    } else {
        QLocale l(QLocale::English, QLocale::UnitedStates);
        QLocale::setDefault(l);
        dynamic_cast<MangoApp*>(qApp)->setLayoutDirection(Qt::LeftToRight);
        dynamic_cast<MangoApp*>(qApp)->removeAllTranslator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want something else - to change language at runtime without special code writing. Using for example environment variable.
Qt has a way to determine the current system language. I just want to deceive it :)

Comment: On my windows machine I add an environment variable LANG=ar_SA.UTF8 and it work for designer.exe.

On Linux you can try to run the app like this:
LANG=en_US.UTF8 app_name.

Another solution is add your own command line and parse it when the application start.

Comment: I.e. you application is successfully change its language by changing `LANG` env variable? I'm trying to change it, but with no effect.
If so, looks like the problem is in my app ;(

Answer (score 0):

Using the `LANGUAGE` (*not* `LANG`) environment variable should definitely change the value returned by `QLocale::system().name()`, because this environment variable has precedence over all other ways to define the application message locale ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63103897)).

I tested it this with Qt 5.12 under Lubuntu 19.10 (means, using the LXQt desktop), and it works. The command was:

```
LANGUAGE=de ./application
```

If this really does not work under Kubuntu, it should be reported as a bug, because then Kubuntu is interfering with the way how an application is told its locale.