# How to find current QLocale in Qt/PyQt/PySide?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, locale, pyside

How can I find the currently active `QLocale`? We can find the default system locale with `QLocale.system()`, but I want something like `QLocale.current()`, to check if the locale changes I am trying to make are actually working.

[The documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocale.html) has lots of methods for setting locales, or finding the properties of a given `QLocale`. But is there a simple method to return the current `QLocale`, so that I can then apply these methods to it (e.g., `name()`)?

**Related questions**

- [How to get current application language](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/7655/)
- [How to force QLocale::system to change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407377/how-to-force-qlocalesystem-to-change)

Comment: What do you mean by "the user can set the QLocale at the command line"? What is the specific mechanism that is being used?

Comment: @ekhumoro I removed that confusing part. I assumed we could find something that can be used any time, just like you could call `QtCore. QLocale.system().name()` any time, regardless of what context you are in. My goal is mainly debugging: I want to check to see if the locale changes I am trying to make are working. But I am assuming that the context doesn't matter too much, that there should be a way to find out the present QLocale, just as there is an easy way to find the default system locale. Maybe that is a bad assumption.

Comment: @ekhumoro I think the answer is that there is no built-in method to do what I'm asking. However, to change the current app's locale you use `QLocale.setDefault(newLocale)`. (Where `newLocale` is a `QLocale` type). But then since you already have `newLocale`, you can apply all the methods you want (e.g., `newLocale.name()`). Does that seem right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to simply use:

```
current_locale = QtCore.QLocale()
```

This will resolve to the *system* locale, unless the default locale has been explicitly re-set using `QLocale.setDefault()`.

So the normal procedure would be: if necessary, set the default locale immediately after the `QApplication` is created. After that, any time a `QLocale` object is created with no arguments, it will either resolve to the locale you originally set yourself, or fall back to the system locale.

This seems to imply that it is best to always construct a new `QLocale` object to obtain information about the locale, rather than caching the information for later re-use.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the current locale by getting an instance of the class:

```
curr_locale = QLocale()
```

And then get the current locale information, e.g.:

```
print(curr_locale.nativeCountryName(), curr_locale.name(), curr_locale.nativeLanguageName())
```

And if you want to change the current locale, e.g.:

```
QLocale.setDefault(QLocale(QLocale.Portuguese, QLocale.Brazil))
```

See the [QLocale documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html) for more methods.